# How to make numbers superscript?

Tags: numbering, superscripts, units

[image]Hello guys,
How to make numbers superscript? Just like in the picture below

Comment: In math mode, use ^(-1).  In text use \textsuperscript{-1}.

Comment: Or siunits package https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx?lang=en

Comment: It works successfully.

Comment: Thank you so much. I hope that one day I can become a master like you.